# Elegant factory of None objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, nonetype

To create an int with default value you would call int(). To create a string with default value you would call str(). What would you call to create an object of NoneType in Python 3?

This is not purely theoretic, you need elegant object factories for defaultdicts and custom type specs when creating and serializing objects.

**EDIT**: specific usage example goes here. I serialize state which consists of multiple variously typed fields. The system is being constantly developed and new fields are being added to the state (it is a chatbot and conversation state with a particular user if you will). I keep a list of serializable fields along with their default object factories — such as int, str, etc. Thanks to it, when deserializing state and a field is not recorded in the persistent storage, it is initialized with a default value using the function. For some fields it is convenient to distinguish between N/A (None) and *something* (even empty string). Obviously `lambda _: None` will work and `type(None)` also will but I just find it awkward and inconsistent that there is no longer any `NoneType` to accompany `int`, `list` and so on (“Explicit is better than implicit”).

Comment: `None` is a singleton and it's always available in global namespace. Having a _factory_ for it has absolutely no sense. What would be equivalent factory of `null`s in Java? If you really need a callable, `lambda: None` would work.

Comment: The idea of a default value does not apply to `None`: [The `None` object](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/none.html)

Comment: Actually `type(None)` can be called and that results in `None`. You could set `none = type(None)` if you really wanted to.

Comment: At least on 2.7 None is a singelton as Lukasz mentions. Using type(None)() would result in TypeError: cannot create 'NoneType' instances.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski comparison to Java is irrelevant here. See my edit for a use example.

Comment: @kabanus it's no longer an error. The constructor returns the same `None` instance, though. So it still is a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

`None` singleton has many semantic meanings: no value, will-be-substituted value, missing value, ignore-this value. If you want to be explicit, then you may create a separate class for empty fields.

```
class EmptyField:

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'EmptyField()'
```

What exactly should be in `EmptyField` is determined by the serialiser.

Comment: A good point. On the other hand built-in types are easier to serialise and store in a database, so None as “no value, possibly will be substituted” seems somewhat justified.

Answer (score 0):

For basic types like `int`, `NoneType`, `dict` and other simple cases there's a natural "factory" in Python - it is `ast.literal_eval`.

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval('None') is None
True

>>> ast.literal_eval('{1: 2}')
{1: 2}

>>> ast.literal_eval('1e6')
1000000.0
```

So if your data is a superposition of basic types (something json-like for instance), then you can parse it with single `ast.literal_eval` call. Unlike `exec` and `eval`, `ast.literal_eval` is much safer as you can't run any code with it.